# How to Enumerate Names of All Named Pipes in a Process?

Tags: c++, c, windows, named-pipes

I need to open a certain named pipe so I can fuzz test it, however my test code does not have access to the same data used to generate the name of the named pipe.  However I can recognize the name of the pipe and then use that name to open up the pipe for fuzzing.

I used this forum post to start enumerating names of the handles on the system:
http://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-enumerate-handles_topic18892.html

However it seems that won't work with named pipes for some reason.

TL;DR: What API(s) do I need to use to list the names of all **named pipes** in the current process on Windows?

Comment: Do you specifically need to enumerate pipes only in the current process? I already have a working named pipe enumeration for Windows, but it's system-wide.

Comment: I only need to iterate over the named pipes in the current process, though I can totally work with enumerating all pipes on the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will enumerate all named pipes in the system, or at the very least put you a step in the right direction.

This works in MinGW when built with -fpermissive. It should work with similar settings in MSVC.

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
// Windows XP
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#endif

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>


// mycreatepipeex.c is at http://www.davehart.net/remote/PipeEx.c
// I created a simple header based on that.    
#include "mycreatepipeex.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <errno.h>

void EnumeratePipes()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;

#define TARGET_PREFIX "//./pipe/"
    const char *target = TARGET_PREFIX "*";

    memset(&FindFileData, 0, sizeof(FindFileData));
    hFind = FindFirstFileA(target, &FindFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        std::cerr << "FindFirstFileA() failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        do
        {
            std::cout << "Pipe: " << TARGET_PREFIX << FindFileData.cFileName << std::endl;
        }
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));

        FindClose(hFind);
    }
#undef TARGET_PREFIX

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    HANDLE read = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE write = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    unsigned char pipe_name[MAX_PATH+1];

    BOOL success = MyCreatePipeEx(&read, &write, NULL, 0, 0, 0, pipe_name);

    EnumeratePipes();

    if ( success == FALSE )
    {
        std::cerr << "MyCreatePipeEx() failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *f = fopen((const char*)pipe_name, "rwb");
    if ( f == NULL )
    {
        std::cerr << "fopen(\"" << pipe_name << "\") failed: " << (int)errno << std::endl;
    }

    CloseHandle(read);
    CloseHandle(write);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll need a bit to verify this works for me, but it looks reasonable.  I'll upvote and resolve this question in about a day or two.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll just note this worked fine on Windows - made slight edits to the target string.  I'm not sure why OP used a macro like that though.

Comment: Easy to switch between "//./pipe/" and L"//./pipe/" in all code at that point. Not that it matters in the sample since it's so short.