# What is the correct format to search for a pipe that begins with a specific string?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I would like to count the number of open pipes, the names of which begin with a specific string. I use the code [the code in Keith4G's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778885/how-to-enumerate-names-of-all-named-pipes-in-a-process) but cannot make FindFirstFileA filter just the pipes beginning with a string.

I call FindFirstFileA like so:

```
hFind = FindFirstFileA(filter, &FindFileData);
```

If filter is `const char* filter = "//./pipe/*";` then all open pipes are counted correctly.

If filter is `const char* filter = "//./pipe/MyPipeNamePrefix*";`, I would expect it to return all pipes that begin with `MyPipeNamePrefix`, but it cannot find any.

I can see the pipe in [Sysinternals Pipelist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd581625.aspx) with the name `MyPipeNamePrefix_{guid}`, I can also see it in powershell, this time with the format `\\.\\pipe\\MyPipeNamePrefix_{guid}` however this filter does not work either. I have tried all manner of backward and forward slashes in varying numbers but none work.

**What is the correct filter to pass to FindFirstFileA to match pipes beginning with a string?**

Comment: Did you try adding an extra \\ before the filter to account for C escaping and/or calling the Unicode version? You're tinkering with one of those special NT (device) namespaces for which special rules I never quite managed to figure out apply and it's hardly surprising if globbing fails to work. To quote MSDN `Most APIs won't support "\\.\"; only those that are designed to work with the device namespace will recognize it.` and the FindFirstFile documentation has no mention of it.

Comment: @doyax, Yes I did. In fact if backslashes are used in the \\.\pipe\ prefix it doesn't work at all (I will update the question for this). I think for now I'll filter on `FindFileData.cFileName` myself since as you say maybe this isn't actually supported in FindFirstFileA?

Comment: Works fine on my machine, either way.  This is not a documented feature, the Windows version should matter a lot.  Mine is 8.1

Comment: For what it's worth, I just tried on a Win 7 machine and it did not work. Using `"\\\\.\\pipe\\*` as the filter returns all pipes, but adding any other characters in addition to the `*` simply returns `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES`. Tried a bunch of combinations using the asterisk, and also `?`.

Comment: That's maybe not what you want, but if you get all the pipes name, filter them afterward with string functions []-->